# use of curly brackets within replicate function in R

Tags: r, montecarlo, replicate

```
B <- 10000
results <- replicate(B, {
  hand <- sample(hands1, 2)
  (hand[1] %in% aces & hand[2] %in% facecard) | (hand[2] %in% aces & hand[1] %in% facecard)
})
mean(results)
```

this piece of code works perfectly and do the desired thi
this is a monte carlo simulation. I don't understand the way they put curly brackets {} in the replicate function. i can understand the function of that code but i cant understand the way they put the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that we have multiple expressions

```
hand <- sample(hands1, 2)
```

is the first expression and the second is

```
 (hand[1] %in% aces & hand[2] %in% facecard) | (hand[2] %in% aces & hand[1] %in% facecard)
```

---

i.e. if there is only a single expression, we don't need to block with `{}`

It is a general case and not related to `replicate` i.e. if we use a `for` loop with a single expression, it doesn't need any `{}`

```
for(i in 1:5)
   print(i)
```

and similarly, something like `if/else`

```
n <- 5
if(n == 5) 
  print(n)
```

It is only needed when we need more than one expression

Comment: So the value passing to the replicate function is the value of the second expression. Am i right.

Comment: @NadikaDushan It is multiple expression and the value you returned is from the last expression evaluated.  The first expression is just `sample`ing which is the main difference in each of the iteration in `replicate`